# RWTime is displaying localtime+1

Tags: c++, rogue-wave

Why RWTime is giving 1 hour more

```
#include <rw/rwtime.h>
#include <rw/rwdate.h>
#include <rw/rstream.h>

main(){
 RWTime t;   // Current time
 RWTime d(RWTime::beginDST(1990, RWZone::local()));
   cout << "Current time:         " << RWDate(t) << " " << t <<
            endl;
   cout << "Start of DST, 1990:   " << RWDate(d) << " " << d <<
           endl;
}
```

Above program prints:

`root@otp42mas:/home/nmsadm/sapna/cProgS# ./a.out

Current time:         10/27/10 10/27/10 17:08:06

Start of DST, 1990:   04/01/90 04/01/90 03:00:00`

But `date` gives:

`root@otp42mas:/home/nmsadm/sapna/cProgS# date

Wed Oct 27 16:08:10 IST 2010`

Comment: I added a "rogue-wave" tag - it might help someone familiar with the library to find your question.

Answer (score 1):

My sixth sense is tingling, it tells me that the answer has something to do with the daylight savings time ... I'm not sure why, though ...

Comment: I think that's a pretty good guess - if IST is Indian Standard Time, then there's apparently no daylight savings time, and it looks like the Rogue Wave library is applying a daylight savings adjustment.

Answer (score 0):

By default `RWZone::local()` will return an RWZone implementation based on North American DST transitions. `RWZone::os()` provides an RWZone implementation based DST transitions derived from the current system time zone. `RWZone::local()` can be updated to use `RWZone::os()` using:

```
RWZone::local(&RWZone::os());
```